# Фреймы в ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, веб-программирование, c#

**Добрый день!**

Бьюсь над проблемой - хочу сделать веб-форму, с меню со ссылками на 6 сторонних страниц, и хочу чтобы эти 6 страниц при нажатию на ссылку в меню отображались во врейме.
Т.е. постоянная статическая картинка сверху экрана, текст небольшой и внизу старница, которую выбрал пользователь.

Использую VS2010

Вставляю в страницу код типа

```
<FRAMESET rowss="30%,70%" frameborder="yes"  framespacing="1" cols="*,*">
<FRAME name="MAIN" src="~/SPages/Main.aspx"> 
<FRAME name="NEWS" src="~/SPages/News.aspx">
</FRAMESET>
```

пишет студия что элемент FRAMESET не поддерживается.

**Подскажите, пожалуйста ,как можно еще сделать?**

Comment: Master page вам в помощь, ей богу.

Comment: начинаю Вас понимать....
а как привязать aspx-страницы к Footer ? (если там будем отображать ) - этот момент не понял(

Comment: это в MASTER page указывается вроде бы... просто в регионе footer-a нужно отображать (по логике) переменную страницу.
добавьте asp:ContentPlaceHolder и в него уже динамически вкладывайте свою страницу.
как это точно сделать - думайте сами, ваш проект)

Answer (score 1):

Если FRAMESET не поддерживается студией, это еще не означает, что он не будет работать в браузере.

Но фреймсеты не вполне удобны для пользователя, лучше и правда использовать MasterPage.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать IFRAME-ом. В основной странице IFRAME а меню JavaScript кодом меняет SRC этого IFRAME. основная страница остается статичной, а динамичсеская часть меняетсе без полного постбака.